# Get result headers with table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, join

I might have not the right vocabulary because I can't find any result, but I will try to be clear:

I'm doing some SQL joins using the abstraction class from CodeIgniter (Active Record) but I have trouble to differentiate the columns.

Here are the columns headers from PHPMyAdmin:
`id, name, owner, id, team, user, id, username, password`

Here are the ones from Active Record:
`id, name, owner, team, user, username, password`

*But* PHPMyAdmin offers to sort the columns properly, event if the field is the name: it keeps track of the table name.

So is it possible to get this kind result, (eventually without portability to other SQL engines):
`teams.id, teams.name, teams.owner, teammates.id, teammates.team, teammates.user, users.id, users.username, users.password`

Or do I have to rename manually each field during the request, with this kind of `SELECT`:
`teams.id AS teams_id`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the active record return a multidimensional array, where a parent array is the column name, and its children are the columns. So you can access them like `$array['column1']['name']` and `$array['column2']['name']`

Comment: I can't find that. Here is a code snippet: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?e5da235ab7a8749a#tDsHq6af1BRDbQF7HJWo6rH4b2BdPw2MEfXhMIQc74M=

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do this as a plain query and execute it, rather than with active record. Active record is not the best at joins...

So take you're query from phpmyadmin and execute it:

```
$query = $this->db->query("well formed query from phpmyadin!");
```

Comment: My requests are pretty simple and it *has* to be portable, so I will stick to Active Record. I think I'll stick to table renaming with my `$this->db->select('teams.id AS teams_id, ...');`